# Can you omit initial message on netstat call in program

Tags: c, bash, command-line

Is there anyway to omit the initial 2 lines when calling `system("netstat -ltnp -a | grep ./server");`?

I dont want my program to read "(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)"

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8091            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      109392/./server     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8101          127.0.0.1:57114         ESTABLISHED 108863/./server     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41238         127.0.0.1:8091          ESTABLISHED 109397/./client     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8091          127.0.0.1:41238         ESTABLISHED 109392/./server     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:57114         127.0.0.1:8101          ESTABLISHED 108865/./client
```

Comment: Is `(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)` being printed to stdout or stderr? Is the rest of the output being printed to stdout or stderr?

Comment: Yes stdout. I'm running my software on the schools Turing server. Assuming it would not show if I was the root but can only imagine if the person that grades it will see a bunch of them when compiled. I made a bash script to sent the output to a text file and it doesn't show up there but when I throw the bash command via ```system(bash)``` it still manages to come out during the process. Any other ways to get this information just incase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trivial solution would be to replace `grep` with e.g. `sed` or Awk, which easily let you add such constraints.

```
system("netstat -ltnp -a | sed -e '1,2d' -e '\\%./server%'");
```

(Properly speaking, the dot should be backslashed, too.)

For anything more involved, perhaps create a parser for the `netstat` output (and/or see if you can get it to emit results in a well-defined machine-readable format).

Are you sure this warning message is printed on standard output, though? Any well-behaved Unix utility should be emitting diagnostic messages to standard error, not standard output. The simple solution then is to redirect standard error to `/dev/null`.